# How To Declare / Store "12:00:00 AM" in a DateTime Variable? (Through military time)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this code:

```
 Dim twelve_AMToday As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 24, 0, 0)
```

But it says "Hour, Minute, and Second parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."

Of course 23, 59, 59 is read as 11:59:59 PM. I've tried 0, 0, 0 but then gives me the date only.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean “then gives me the date only”? `0, 0, 0` is correct.

Comment: Actually what should be your output ??

Comment: I debug and only shows #6/27/2014#, no time values at all. @false

Comment: My output or value should be #6/27/2014 12:00:00AM# @hector

Comment: “What it says in the debugger” is not “output”. Actually write it out somewhere.

Comment: Still 6/27/2014 in a MessageBox. :( @false

Answer (score 0):

You get it when you use Today

```
 Dim twelve_AMToday As DateTime = Today
```

If you want to add days put this code under it.

```
  twelve_AMToday = twelve_AMToday.AddYears(0).AddMonths(0).AddDays(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Dim twelve_AMToday As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0)
    Dim s As String = twelve_AMToday.ToLongDateString & " " & twelve_AMToday.ToLongTimeString
```

What you see in the debugger will be the same for the datetime, but once the datetime is converted to a string you will see that it does have the time you want.  If the time is all zeroes the debugger doesn't show the time for datetimes, but it is there.